# Обработчик события .on()

Tags: jquery

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    // Код
    return false;
});
```

Прочитал в [документации](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On) что можно переделать на:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function() {
    // Код
    return false;
});
```

> handler — функция, которая будет установлена в качестве обработчика.
>   Вместо функции, можно указать значение false, это будет эквивалентно
>   установке такой функции: function(){return false;}.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(false) {
    // Код
});

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', false) {
    // Код
});
```

Но что-то не чего не получается, я не как понял или просто не правильно прописываю?

Comment: какая у Вас задача? Не могу уловить смысл установки обработчика события, который всегда будет возвращать `false`.

Comment: @XelaNimed Смысл очевидный - отключить работу внутристраничных ссылок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрите в консоль браузера, наверняка ошибки вываливаются. В [документации(англ)](http://api.jquery.com/on/) к jQuery приведен пример:

```
$( "a.disabled" ).on( "click", false );
```

У вас написано лишнее

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', false) {
   // Код
});
```

Comment: То есть, если вместо функции я укажу false, то внутри функции я уже какой-то код написать не с могу?

Comment: @РодионПоляков Ну конечно. Цель такого сокращения - не писать функцию. В исходниках _jQuery_ при этом подставляется пустая функция с возвратом `false`. Если нужен код, то пишите функцию, которая после выполнения кода возвращает `false`